# The existence of a holomorphic map from disk to disk with given value and derivative at a point

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to solve the follwing question from past papers of a competitive exam.

Let $\mathbb D=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|<1\}$ Which of the following are correct?

1. $\exists$ a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ with $f(0)=0,f'(0)=2$
2. $\exists$ a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ with $f(\frac34)=\frac34,f'(\frac23)=\frac34$
3. $\exists$ a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ with $f(\frac34)=-\frac34,f'(\frac34)=-\frac34$
4. $\exists$ a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ with $f(\frac12)=-\frac12,f'(\frac14)=1$

It may have more than one option correct.

What I found is that 1. can not be true since [Schwarz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) gives $|f'(0)|\le 1$

But I am unable to conclude anything about the other options because I could not use Schwarz lemma in other options since $f(0)$ is not $0$ there.

I am very new to complex analysis. So may be the question is not too hard to answer but I am completely stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cases 2 and 3 you can construct the function explicitly, for instance, by taking $f(z) = 3/4\, z + 3/16$ and $f(z) = -3/4\, z - 3/16$, respectively.

To see that these functions map the disk into itself, we note that
for $|z|<1$, $|f(z)|\leq \frac{3}{4}|z| + \frac{3}{16} \leq \frac{15}{16}<1$.

The fourth case seems to be more difficult. Below is a brute force way of showing that the statement is false, though there may be an elementary argument showing the same.

We will use the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem)

> If $f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic, then for all $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{D}$,
> $$ \left|\frac{f(z_1) - f(z_2)}{1-\overline{f(z_1)} \, f(z_2)} \right|\leq \left|\frac{z_1-z_2}{1-\bar{z}_1  z_2 } \right|
> $$
> and for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$,
> $$ \frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}. $$
> If equality holds throughout one of these inequalities, then $f$ is a Möbius automorphism of $\mathbb{D}.$

Let us first show that $f(1/4)=-1/4.$

By applying the 2nd Schwarz-Pick inequality to $f'(1/4)=1$ we first find that $|f(1/4)|\leq 1/4$.

Then we apply the 1st Schwarz-Pick inequality to $f(1/2)=-1/2$ and find that
$$
\left|\frac{1+2 \,f(1/4)}{2 + f(1/4)}\right| \leq \frac{2}{7}.
$$
Now, if we look at the function
$$
g(w) = \frac{1+2 w}{2 + w},
$$
we note that $|g(w)|\geq 2/7$ in the region $|w|\leq 1/4$, and equality holds only for one point, $w=-1/4$ (you can for instance use the fact that an analytic function attains its minimum on the boundary of a domain, then substitute $w = e^{i\theta}/4$ and apply calculus tools). Therefore, $f(1/4)=-1/4$.

The problem of finding a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ with $f(1/2) = -1/2$  and $f(1/4) = -1/4$ is a simple case of the [Nevanlinna-Pick interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna%E2%80%93Pick_interpolation) problem.
The determinant of the Pick matrix is zero, hence the solution must be unique, i.e. $f(z) = -z$. However, in that case $f'(1/4) \neq 1$, therefore the fourth statement is false.

Comment: Thnx for your help.Can you please explain how can I use this theorem?because this theorem needs two functional values f(z1) and f(z2) but any of the option does not have that.

Comment: ok let me try now.

Comment: this can be applied to option 3 only,How can I use this for other 2 options?

Comment: thnx a lot for your help.Two little questions-if Schwarz-Pick condition is satisfied for a particular z,can we conclude existence of function?and how can I construct these functions?

Comment: thnx for your help.lastly can you please tell me how can I eliminate option 4?any direct application of any theorem?

Comment: Lots of thnx for giving your valuable time.It is really helpful. Thnx again @Georgy

Comment: It will be really nice if any such elementary way exists.

Comment: one more question if you don't mind please..for the 3rd case will the function f(z)=-3z/4-3/16 work?

Comment: Thank you very much @Georgy

Comment: @usermath & @  Georgy Ivanov ): I could not understand that how $|g(w)|\ge 2/7$ in $|w|\le 1/4$ ? Can anyone explain it for me?

Comment: @Panja.S.
A silly brute force method:

1. $g(e^{i \theta}) =\frac{2 \left(2+e^{i \theta }\right)}{8+e^{i \theta }}$

2. Instead of minimizing $|g(e^{i\theta})|$ we can minimize 
$f(\theta) = |g(e^{i\theta})|^2 = \frac{4 (4 \cos (\theta )+5)}{16 \cos (\theta )+65}$

3. Calculate the derivative and find the minimum using first-year calculus:
$f'(\theta)=-\frac{720 \sin (\theta )}{(16 \cos (\theta )+65)^2}$

Comment: Correction: $g(e^{i\theta}/4)$, not $g(e^{i\theta})$